# Avoid deleting cache on browser on react new version after upload

Tags: reactjs, nginx, caching

Currently We have a ReactJs App that constantly is pushing new features and our users are pissed off because some old features don't run as expected; this is due that there is a new Javascript file  for it to be rendered on the build folder.

There is a solution for this? So far I've changed NGINX expiration but this not seem to be a final solution since still the old javascript being rendered.

Comment: If I get your problem correctly, you've got an issue because old files get replaced when you're delivering new features. You would like to continuously deploy new features without the risk of breaking older versions of your application. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. the thing is that we are editing various react modules that our users don't seem to get unless they clear their browser cache. and so far is a pain because people think the app no longer works.